How do I get a focus pixel function based on a given buffer containing surrounding pixels?
I want to calculate the percentage of built-up pixels surrounding each built-up pixel within a 100 sq.km. I know focal function in R can be of use. But I want to understand the actual algorithm behind the function in Python. Can anyone help me understand this? I want to get around this type of neighborhood pixel analyses.

Kindly mention any one tool, since as per the policy of this site, you can ask for one tool in each question.

Sure. I have edited the question. Python would be preferable.
